# MySQL Query Between Two Ranges

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help with a query.  I am taking input from a user where they enter a range between 1-100.  So it could be like 30-40 or 66-99.  Then I need a query to pull data from a table that has a high_range and a low_range to find a match to any number in their range.

So if a user did 30-40 and the table had entries for 1-80, 21-33, 32-40, 40-41, 66-99, and 1-29 it would find all but the last two in the table.

What is the easiest why to do this?

Thanks

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID between 30 AND 40;

Comment: @Farkie Looks like you have the correct answer. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (high_range between 30 AND 40 OR low_range between 30 and 40)`

Comment: :) Want me to post as official answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly (i.e. you want any range that overlaps the one entered by the user), I'd say:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE low <= $high AND high >= $low
```

Comment: Not quite sure why my answer got down voted, I believe it does exactly what the OP asked for. Of course low and high are the table columns and $high and $low are the user inputs.

Comment: I didn't downvoted but I think we can just use `BETWEEN` operator since OP wants data inclusive but anyways your answer is correct.

Comment: @Rahul, BETWEEN works if you compare 3 values (i.e., one value against one range). Here we have 4 to compare (2 ranges).

Comment: I thought I had tried your solution and it didn't work, but I guess I was mistaken.  So far it's pulling the correct entries.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that the range is stored in this format `low-high`. If that is the case, then this is a poor design. I suggest splitting the values into two columns: `low`, and `high`.

If you already have the values split, you can use some statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE low <= $needleHigherBound AND high >= $needleLowerBound
```

If you have the values stored in one column, and insist they stay so, You might find the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function of MySQL useful. But in this case, you'll have to write a complicated query to parse all the values of all the rows, and then compare them to your search values. It seems like a lot of effort to cover up a design flaw.